# two variable loop "for" output in the right sequence

Tags: r, loops

How can I make this loop, appearing in the same sequence as dataframe(a,b).

```
a <- seq(1,36,2)
b <- seq(2,36,2)
c <- NULL
for (i in a) {
  for (j in b) {
    d <- cbind(i, j)
    c <- rbind(c,d)

  }

}
c
```

The output *c* gives *j* in the order I want, but *i* repeats itself every 18 times.

This is the way I want it

```
data.frame(a,b)
```

Comment: What is wrong with using `data.frame(a,b)` ?

Comment: for (i in seq1) {
  for (j in seq2) { 
    ab <- cbind( chi=
      as.character(cbind(c(
        rep(fisher.test(rbind(c(ll[i,1],ll[i,2]), c(ll[j,1],ll[j,2])))$p.value,2)))),
      fish = (  c(
          rep(prop.test(rbind(c(ll[i,1],ll[i,2]), c(ll[j,1],ll[j,2])))$p.value,2))))
   ab <- cbind(ab, i,j)
    kk <- rbind(kk,ab)
 }
}

Comment: @RonakShah I cannot use data frame using a formula so many times

Comment: @MauritsEvers because I have to run fisher.test and prop.test multiple times, only a loop would do that. I think so

Comment: @MauritsEvers and I have to store the output in a data.frame

Comment: why don't you just loop over dataframe rows, like:`df <- data.frame(a,b) ; apply(df, 1, function(x) prop.test(x[1],x[2]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two loops, just one.

```
a <- seq(1,36,2)
b <- seq(2,36,2)
c <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(a)){
  d<-cbind(a[i],b[i])
  c<-rbind(c,d)
  }
```